Merge gstremer with gtk4 using wayland
I am using gstreamer to play recorded video with audio. Now I need to have GUI support to play , pause and resume the video for the gstreamer, for that I am using GTK4 window . I need to have both gstreamer window and buttons regarding to control the video in one window . For that , I need to merge gstreamer window with gtk window . Here I am attaching the code which I have tried for that
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>

int play_flag = 0;

/* Structure to contain all our information, so we can pass it around */
typedef struct _CustomData {
    GstElement *pipeline;          /* Our pipeline */
    GtkWidget *sink_widget;        /* Widget where our video will be displayed */
    GtkWidget *slider;             /* Slider widget to keep track of current position */
    GtkWidget *streams_list; 
    gulong slider_update_signal_id; /* Signal ID for the slider update signal */
    GstState state;                /* Current state of the pipeline */
    gint64 duration;               /* Duration of the clip, in nanoseconds */
} CustomData;

GstElement *source;
GstElement *decode;
GstElement *video_queue, *v4l2convert, *videosink, *audio_queue, *audioconvert, *audioresample, *audiosink;

/* This function is called when the PLAY button is clicked */
static void play_cb(GtkButton *button, CustomData *data) {
    if (play_flag == 1) {
        gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);
        play_flag = 0;
    }
    gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
}

/* This function is called when the PAUSE button is clicked */
static void pause_cb(GtkButton *button, CustomData *data) {
    gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
}

/* This function is called when the STOP button is clicked */
static void stop_cb(GtkButton *button, CustomData *data) {
    gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);
}

/* This function is called when the main window is closed */
static void delete_event_cb(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, CustomData *data) {
    stop_cb(NULL, data);
}

/* This function is called when the slider changes its position. We perform a seek to the new position here. */
static void slider_cb(GtkRange *range, CustomData *data) {
    gdouble value = gtk_range_get_value(GTK_RANGE(data->slider));
    gst_element_seek_simple(data->pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_KEY_UNIT,
                            (gint64)(value * GST_SECOND));
}

/* Dynamic pad handler to link decodebin pads */
static void pad_added_handler(GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, CustomData *data) {
    GstPad *sink_pad = NULL;
    GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
    GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
    const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;

    new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(new_pad);
    new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure(new_pad_caps, 0);
    new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name(new_pad_struct);

    if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "video/x-raw")) {
        sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(video_queue, "sink");
    } else if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "audio/x-raw")) {
        sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(audio_queue, "sink");
    }

    if (gst_pad_is_linked(sink_pad)) {
        g_object_unref(sink_pad);
        if (new_pad_caps != NULL)
            gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
        return;
    }

    if (gst_pad_link(new_pad, sink_pad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK) {
        g_printerr("Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);
    } else {
        g_print("Link succeeded (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);
    }

    if (new_pad_caps != NULL)
        gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
    gst_object_unref(sink_pad);
}

/* This function is called periodically to refresh the GUI */
static gboolean refresh_ui(CustomData *data) {
    gint64 current = -1;

    /* We do not want to update anything unless we are in the PAUSED or PLAYING states */
    if (data->state < GST_STATE_PAUSED)
        return TRUE;

    /* If we didn't know it yet, query the stream duration */
    if (!GST_CLOCK_TIME_IS_VALID(data->duration)) {
        if (!gst_element_query_duration(data->pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, &data->duration)) {
            g_printerr("Could not query current duration.\n");
        } else {
            /* Set the range of the slider to the clip duration, in SECONDS */
            gtk_range_set_range(GTK_RANGE(data->slider), 0, (gdouble)data->duration / GST_SECOND);
        }
    }

    if (gst_element_query_position(data->pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, &current)) {
        /* Block the "value-changed" signal, so the slider_cb function is not called
         * (which would trigger a seek the user has not requested) */
        g_signal_handler_block(data->slider, data->slider_update_signal_id);
        /* Set the position of the slider to the current pipeline position, in SECONDS */
        gtk_range_set_value(GTK_RANGE(data->slider), (gdouble)current / GST_SECOND);
        /* Re-enable the signal */
        g_signal_handler_unblock(data->slider, data->slider_update_signal_id);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

/* This function is called when an error message is posted on the bus */
static void error_cb(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    /* Print error details on the screen */
    gst_message_parse_error(msg, &err, &debug_info);
    g_printerr("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME(msg->src), err->message);
    g_printerr("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
    g_clear_error(&err);
    g_free(debug_info);

    /* Set the pipeline to READY (which stops playback) */
    gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);
}

/* This function is called when an End-Of-Stream message is posted on the bus.
 * We just set the pipeline to READY (which stops playback) */
static void eos_cb(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
    g_print("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
    play_flag = 1;
}

/* This function is called when the pipeline changes states. We use it to
 * keep track of the current state. */
static void state_changed_cb(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
    GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
    gst_message_parse_state_changed(msg, &old_state, &new_state, &pending_state);
    if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC(msg) == GST_OBJECT(data->pipeline)) {
        data->state = new_state;
        g_print("State set to %s\n", gst_element_state_get_name(new_state));
        if (old_state == GST_STATE_READY && new_state == GST_STATE_PAUSED) {
            /* For extra responsiveness, we refresh the GUI as soon as we reach the PAUSED state */
            refresh_ui(data);
        }
    }
}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, CustomData *data) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *box;
    GtkWidget *button_play;
    GtkWidget *button_pause;
    GtkWidget *button_stop;
    GstBus *bus;
    GstElement *gtkglsink;

    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Video Player");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 600);

    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), box);

    /* Initialize our data structure */
    memset(data, 0, sizeof(CustomData));
    data->duration = GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE;

    // Create GStreamer pipeline
    data->pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("video-audio-player");

    source = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "file-source");
    decode = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decoder");
    video_queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "video-queue");
    v4l2convert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "video-convert");
    videosink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "video-output");
    audio_queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "audio-queue");
    audioconvert = gst_element_factory_make("audioconvert", "audio-convert");
    audioresample = gst_element_factory_make("audioresample", "audio-resample");
    audiosink = gst_element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "audio-output");

    if (!source || !decode || !video_queue || !v4l2convert || !videosink ||
        !audio_queue || !audioconvert || !audioresample || !audiosink) {
        g_printerr("Not all elements could be created.\n");
        return;
    }

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "location", "my_video-4.mp4", NULL);

    /* Build the pipeline. We add all elements into the pipeline */
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(data->pipeline), source, decode, video_queue, v4l2convert, videosink,
                     audio_queue, audioconvert, audioresample, audiosink, NULL);

    /* Link the file source to the decoder */
    if (!gst_element_link(source, decode)) {
        g_printerr("Failed to link filesrc and decodebin.\n");
        gst_object_unref(data->pipeline);
        return;
    }

    // Link decodebin dynamically
    g_signal_connect(decode, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(pad_added_handler), data);

    /* Link video elements */
    if (!gst_element_link_many(video_queue, v4l2convert, videosink, NULL)) {
        g_printerr("Video elements could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref(data->pipeline);
        return;
    }

    /* Link audio elements */
    if (!gst_element_link_many(audio_queue, audioconvert, audioresample, audiosink, NULL)) {
        g_printerr("Audio elements could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref(data->pipeline);
        return;
    }

    // Add the video sink widget to the UI only if the sink is a gtksink or gtkglsink
    if (g_strcmp0(gst_element_get_name(videosink), "gtksink") == 0) {
        g_object_get(videosink, "widget", &data->sink_widget, NULL);
    }

    if (data->sink_widget) {
        gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), data->sink_widget);
    } else {
        g_printerr("No video widget could be retrieved from the videosink.\n");
    }

    // Continue setting up the rest of the UI and pipeline handling...

    button_play = gtk_button_new_with_label("Play");
    button_pause = gtk_button_new_with_label("Pause");
    button_stop = gtk_button_new_with_label("Stop");

    data->slider = gtk_scale_new_with_range(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 1);
    gtk_scale_set_draw_value(GTK_SCALE(data->slider), 0);
    data->slider_update_signal_id = g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(data->slider), "value-changed", G_CALLBACK(slider_cb), data);

    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), button_play);
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), button_pause);
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), button_stop);
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), data->slider);

    g_signal_connect(button_play, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(play_cb), data);
    g_signal_connect(button_pause, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(pause_cb), data);
    g_signal_connect(button_stop, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(stop_cb), data);

    gtk_widget_show(window);

    bus = gst_element_get_bus(data->pipeline);
    gst_bus_add_signal_watch(bus);
    g_signal_connect(bus, "message::error", G_CALLBACK(error_cb), data);
    g_signal_connect(bus, "message::eos", G_CALLBACK(eos_cb), data);
    g_signal_connect(bus, "message::state-changed", G_CALLBACK(state_changed_cb), data);

    // Start playing
    gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    
        /* Register a function that GLib will call every second */
  //  g_timeout_add(1000, (GSourceFunc)refresh_ui, &data);
        g_timeout_add_seconds(1, (GSourceFunc)refresh_ui, data);
    
    /* Free resources */
    gst_object_unref(bus);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;
    CustomData data;
     gst_init(&argc, &argv);
    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), &data);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}

If I use gtksink to merge gstreamer with gtk , I am getting two different windows i.e gstreamer to play video and GTK4 window with buttons to play, pause and resume the video in gstreamer .
But I need the buttons to control the video and rendering the video using gstreamer in one window.
Can anybody help me to come out of this issue . Or any other alternative methods to merge gstreamer with gtk4 window is highly appreciable ..

Use gtksink instead of autovideosink. Here is the documentation:
GStreamer GtkSink
it accepts gtkwidget object:
GtkWidget *window, *playerWindow;
window = gtk_application_window_new(app);

videosink = gst_element_factory_make("gtksink", "video-output");
g_object_get(G_OBJECT(videosink), "widget", &playerWindow, NULL);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), playerWindow);
g_object_unref(playerWindow);

then assign other properties and buttons to the window object.

Thank you for your reply , I tried by changing autovideosink to gtksink but no use . No window is displaying while running the application by modifying to gtksink by issuing some critical warnings . Here I am attaching the warnings regarding to it .
No video widget could be retrieved from the videosink.
(video:5261): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 11:18:29.503: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'
(video:5261): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 11:18:29.503: cannot add class private field to invalid type ''

I edited my answer, I had at least one typo (set instead of get) and also I forgot gtksink does not create top level window and top level GTK window must be created before.
